# Strange JSON Deserialization c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm having troubles with some Deserialization because I'm not receiving an object like I'm used to but an array. Lets to the code, how I've being doing it:

**JSON received:**

```
[{"gcm_regID":"fsdf2156fw62f1wfwe512g"}]
```

**Deserialization**

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Gcm>(response);
```

**Handlers Tried:**

```
public class Gcm
{
    public List<Gcm_reg> gcm_regID { get; set; }
}
public class Gcm_reg
{
    public string gcm_regID { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried just the Gcm_reg as well and nothing seems to work. How can I deserialize this? By the way, I'm using the newsoft JSON.

Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 IEnumerable<Gcm_reg> result =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Gcm_reg>>(response);
```

You can deserialize the object as an array or IEnumerable

Comment: It worked. Can you explain how can I form similar objects to send? The server is shitty and I'm trying to do posts but it receives the same kind of JSON starting with [

Comment: create a array of the object you want to send and then serialize it. e.g JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new []{whateverobject_instance})

Comment: to send define  a list of Gcm_reg type and fill the list by using Add method and send the list to server

Comment: try this JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new []{gcm_reginstance})

Answer (score 2):

Object should be like

```
public class Gcm
{
    public string gcm_regID { get; set; }
}
```

So Try it

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Gcm>>(response);
```

You can directly generate classes from Json by using [link](http://json2csharp.com/)

To create same type of object

```
var outputList = new List<Gcm>();

//loop through this part based on number of input
var itemToAdd = new Gcm();
itemToAdd .regID  = 'something';
outputList.Add(itemToAdd );
```

and send **outputList** to server.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using that but it didn't worked its because of that that I'm here :( http://image.prntscr.com/image/3f1129357ee446a98e39131749279845.png   you can see that I'm using the class Gcm_reg and nothing

Comment: @Antoine missed the array part.. corrected...please try again

Comment: Now it works :) can you explain me how can I create a similar request? The server only receives in that kind of info instead of normal objects -.-'